# Android: Can I get the ID of the layout of an activity in code outside of this activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have a plain class (not an activity), which has a reference to an activity. Is it possible and how, to obtain the ID of the layout file which is used as content view by that activity?

Comment: Sure, you can just pass in the same `int` to your class as you used in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

As wsanville pointed out, you can just pass the int you're using for the layout to the constructor of the non-activity class you have. I'm assuming you're constructing said class in the onCreate method of the activity. So:

```
public void onCreate(bundle icicle){
  ...other stuff...
  setContentView(R.id.layout_id);
  OtherClass myClass = new OtherClass(R.id.layout_id);

  ...other stuff...

}
```

There is unfortunently no method I can find on the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) documentation that is a "get" version of the `setContentView` method.

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate my question correctly: I have a reference to the activity, but I don't which is the ID of content view. My class is  not instantiated directly by my code, and there are multiple points in the app, where this class is instantiate and the activity is passed in. However, I found that there is a built-in android ID: android.R.id.content which is the built-in ID of the content view. Let's see if this ID will work.